# Email a photo from Photos.

Tags: macos

I simply want to email a photo from Photos. When I click on the share button, I do not get a message box to address an email

Comment: Do you have an account in your Mail app?

Comment: Is your default email app set to Mac Mail or to a third-party app?

Answer (score 1):

The share button doesn't bring up an address box, it bring up a set of choices, depending on what apps/services you have installed...

[image]

After clicking Mail, a new Mail should open, with the cursor set ready to add an address...

[image]